# How do i correctly query my mongo db using shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

First time using Mongo Shell. Trying to do a simple query but get a syntax error.
Example given in [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) `db.bios.find( { _id: 5 } )`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try belows:

```
db.polls.find({"_id":ObjectId("542642....")})
```

the attribute is not a String or Integer but an Object

Thanks.